# Oracle SQl Developer ORA-01017: invalid username/password; login denied

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have create user and trying to use to make new Connection with that user but im unable to get connect , i have provide that image below

[image]

but i have also tried with some other methods

but i got this type of responses

**ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable**

can any anyone help me out .......????

[image]

Comment: Please execute `TNSPING yourtnsentryname`

Comment: in the window where you created your user, change it's password to what you THINK it should be - or make sure you're providing the right password or that it's not case sensitive